# How Do I Specify Dynamic Page Footer & Header in HTML2PDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2pdf

I'm trying to convert a html page to PDF with [HTML2PDF](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf). HTML page has a form and this form contains textareas with dynamic heights. The height of the textarea is adjusted according to the text in it.

[image]

Problem sample is in [here](https://codepen.io/ogzhncrt/pen/LYRVPpZ).

```
<div class="page-content">
<a href="#" id='download'>Download</a><br>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="" rows="" style='height:320px;'></textarea><br>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="" style='height:420px;' rows=""></textarea><br>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="" style='height:250px;' rows=""></textarea><br>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="" style='height:278px;' rows=""></textarea><br>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="" style='height:176px;' rows=""></textarea><br>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="" style='height:114px;' rows=""></textarea><br>
</div>
```

As you can see in the example, I get results similar to the image below. In the sample, I fixed height of texareas. It is determined dynamically on the page I am dealing with.

**You can find a sample image below for the result I want to get;**

[image]

Any help or advice can be helpful. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197322/how-do-i-specify-a-header-footer-for-html2pdf-to-use-when-rendering-a-pdf) but the form has multiple pages and I don't have any idea how can I set page footer and header dynamically.

Comment: this isn't a javascript question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML2PDF has options listed in [here](https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/#options). Margin and pagebreak option solved the problem. I used options below.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('page-content')[0];
var opt = {
      margin:       0.5, //margin for pages
      filename:     '<?php echo $real_data['applicant_name']; ?>.pdf',
      image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
      html2canvas:  { scale: 1 },
      jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' },
      pagebreak:    { mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy'] } //It determines how HTML elements should be split.
    };

    
html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
```